# ToString[n] in pattern replace does not take the value of n

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I would like to convert expression to C++ code.

Based on these demostrations.

```
Clear[n]
Power[x, 2] /. {Power[x, n_Integer] -> n}
n = 3;
Symbol["xp" <> ToString[Evaluate[n]]]
(**output 2 and xp3**)
```

I try this

```
 Clear[n]
 Power[x, 3] /. {Power[x, n_] -> 
   Symbol["xp" <> ToString[Evaluate[n]]]}
 Power[x, 3] /. {Power[x, n_] -> "xp" <> ToString[n]}
```

however it gives

```
 xpn
 xpn
```

Comment: Use `RuleDelayed`: `Clear[n]
Power[x, 3] /. {Power[x, n_] :> Symbol["xp" <> ToString[Evaluate[n]]]}
Power[x, 3] /. {Power[x, n_] :> "xp" <> ToString[n]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output as `String`

```
 res = Power[x, 3] /. Power[x, n_] :> "xp" <> ToString[n]

"xp3"
```

Output as `Symbol`

```
 res = Power[x, 3] /. Power[x, n_] :> "xp" <> ToString[n] // ToExpression

 Head @ res
```

Symbol